# Google Map Android v2 Zoom Level Detection Inside a Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to detect the Zoom Level in a Google Map. My Map is inside a Fragment which extends another **Fragment**.

I have implemented the OnCameraChangeListener in my class.

This is the Code that I have written to Detect the Zoom Level Change:

```
private float currentZoom = -1;

public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener()
{
    return new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position)
        {
            if(currentZoom != position.zoom)
            {
                currentZoom = position.zoom;


                Context context = mContext;
                CharSequence text = Float.toString(currentZoom);
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }

        }
    };
}

// This is the Method that was created after Implementing the OnCameraChangeListener
@Override
public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
    getCameraChangeListener();
}
```

When I Open the App in the Phone and try **zooming in** or **zooming out**, nothing happens. Normally after reading the answers from other Questions regarding Zoom Level detection, this is the Code that I came up with. But it didn't work.

Please let me know how I can make it work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign that `GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener` to your GoogleMap instance. Here is a sample code that might help you to figure out the way to do it:

```
public void prepareMap(){
    mMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        setupMap(googleMap);
      }
    });
}

private void setupMap(GoogleMap googleMap){
  mMap = googleMap;
  mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(getCameraChangeListener());
}

public GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener getCameraChangeListener() {
  return new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        if(currentZoom != position.zoom) {
            currentZoom = position.zoom;

            Context context = mContext;
            CharSequence text = Float.toString(currentZoom);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
          }
      }
  };
}
```

Comment: So, I just needed to Assign the Listener to where I instantiate the Map! That really solved the problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The onCameraChangeListener is to be set on an instance of the GoogleMap object. More details at http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html